# Protractor webdriver-manager error: "WebDriverError: Unable to determine type from: E. Last 1 characters read: E"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, webdriver-manager, iedriverserver

I have been running Protractor tests against Chrome and I have recently encountered a need to test against IE. I follow the standard procedure to set up the selenium server(webdriver-manager update=>webdriver-manager start), then I run my tests using protractor conf.js. My capabilities are straightforward with {"browserName":"internet explorer", "version":"11"}.

I encounter the following error on seemingly random tests runs. I'm using IEDriverServerv3.14.0.

```
{ WebDriverError: Unable to determine type from: E. Last 1 characters read: E
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08- 02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: '******', ip: '******', os.name: 'Windows 
Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\admin-jdwyer2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\admin-jdwyer2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\admin-jdwyer2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) name: 'WebDriverError', remoteStacktrace: '' }
```

I have searched for solutions but the only mention I could find of this error is [here](https://www.ranorex.com/forum/selenium-webdriver-error-http-remote-request-time--t12271.html). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please let me know if this post needs more context. I will be happy to answer any questions.

Comment: I also just ran into this problem. What method are you starting your selenium server? How are you starting your test? Could you share the code you use to connect to your selenium server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a synchronization issue with my code since I'm running tests with Protractor using `async/await`. In my `conf.js` file I use the `onPrepare()` function to set up variables/settings before the test starts. Inside `onPrepare()` I was maximizing the window with `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`. The trouble happened when I didn't use `await` to synchronize the `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();` call with the rest of my tests so it would maximize the window randomly near the beginning of the test and throw an error.

I fixed this by making `onPrepare()` use `async`(ie change `onPrepare()` to `async onPrepare()` and changing `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();` to `await browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`